# ggplot2: group data.frame in facets according to some criteria

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have a data.frame containing the data I want to plot, what is the easiest way to "group" data in the different plots of a facet_wrap (or facet_grid) ?

To make a concrete example, if the data frame is like:

```
ID | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5
....(data)....
```

I would like to have P1,P2,P3 over ID in the first facet, P4 over ID in the second and P5 over ID in the third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt I made an example that exactly mimics yours, but hopefully you'll get the point. The trick to ggplot2 graphics is to put your data into long format with `melt()`. Then you can create a `facet`ing variable according to how you want to group them. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(ID = rnorm(10), P1 = rnorm(10), P2 = rnorm(10), P3 = rnorm(10), P4 = rnorm(10), P5 = rnorm(10)) 
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = 1)
#Create faceting variable
dat.m <- transform(dat.m, facet = ifelse(variable %in% c("P1", "P2", "P3"), 1, ifelse(variable == "P4", 2,3)))

ggplot(dat.m, aes(ID, value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~facet)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking to use `cyl` as both a faceting and a grouping variable.

Here, I first create a second variable -- `cyl_class` -- to be used as the faceting variable, and continue to group using `cyl`:

```
library(ggplot2)

mpg$cyl_class <- cut(mpg$cyl,
                    breaks=c(3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 8.5),
                    labels=c("4", "5", "6-8"))

p <- qplot(cty, hwy, group=cyl, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl_class) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=factor(cyl))) +
    scale_colour_discrete()
```

The colours could be improved (for better contrast), and the example's kind of silly, but the general approach is sound and easily adaptable.

[image]