# Facetting by groups with ggplot2: code yields a single graph with no facets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I have based my code on [this example on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360561/ggplot2-group-data-frame-in-facets-according-to-some-criteria). My first attempt works fine, as shown here:
[image]

Then I tried doing the same with three groups. I am grouping like this:

```
df.m <- transform(df.m, facet=ifelse(df.m$variable %in% c(var11, var12), 'One',
                                 ifelse(df.m$variable %in% c(var21, var22), 'Two', 'Three')))
g <- ggplot(df.m, aes(group=facet, x=Years, y=value, colour=variable, shape=variable))
g <- g + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~facet)
```

With this code, I just end up with a single plot with all the variables. No faceting happens. I think I am doing something wrong with the `ifelse`, but I'm not sure.

As requested, this is the output of `head(df.m)`:

```
  Years variable     value facet
1  1997     var11 0.1245161     One
2  1998     var11 0.1154599     One
3  1999     var11 0.1151908     One
4  2000     var11 0.1209199     One
5  2001     var11 0.1321990     One
6  2002     var11 0.1476364     One
```

Comment: Are you getting an error from `transform`?  I did when trying to recreate this because there were no quotes around the levels of the factor you are matching to. As in `%in% c("var11", "var12")`.

Comment: Can you show us `head(df.m)`?

Comment: @aosmith How did you even get that far? I copied the code for `dat.m` from the linked question, renamed if `df.m` for this question, but there's no columns or values called anything like "var21". Can't reproduce anything without data...

Comment: Oh, in my code, var11, etc. are vectors I use to build the data frame. `df.m` is the melted data frame. Will it help if I post the entire code here?

Comment: No. It will only help if you show us a small bit of `df.m` and a small bit of `var11`.

Comment: @shujaa I just changed the names from the linked example `dat.m` from P1-P5 to var11-var13.  If I did that wrong, my guess of the problem could also be wrong. ;)

Comment: @SeñorO : added the `head(df.m)` in my question.

Comment: @ChthonicProject the problem is not `ggplot` but that your column `facet` only contains one unique value. Check `unique(df.m$facet)` to make sure.

Comment: @SeñorO You are right. I am trying to create three values: 'One', 'Two' and 'Three' with the `ifelse` statement in my code (as posted in the question). But clearly, that is not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem is because you are missing the quotes in the vector you are comparing against with `%in%`.  But the reason you were getting error messages is a bit more complex than that.  You must have objects in your workspace named `var11`, `var12`, etc.

Starting with a clean workspace:

```
require(reshape2)
dat = data.frame(ID = rnorm(10), var11 = rnorm(10), 
               var12 = rnorm(10), var21 = rnorm(10), var22 = rnorm(10), 
               var13 = rnorm(10), var23 = rnorm(10)) 
df.m = melt(dat, id.vars = 1)
```

If I do this, I get an error message when I run transform:

```
dfm2 = transform(df.m, facet=ifelse(variable %in% c(var11, var12), 'One',
                                 ifelse(variable %in% c(var21, var22), 'Two', 'Three')))
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'var11' not found
```

Now I create some vector objects with the same names in my workspace:

```
var11 = 1
var12 = 2
var21 = 1
var22 = 2
var13 = 1

dfm2 = transform(df.m, facet=ifelse(variable %in% c(var11, var12), 'One',
                                 ifelse(variable %in% c(var21, var22), 'Two', 'Three')))
```

Wah-lah, no error message and one level for the `facet` variable instead of three.  Essentially, you never had any matches so the last level (`Three`) is assigned to everything.

You need those quotes to refer to a character vector instead of the objects.

```
transform(df.m, facet=ifelse(variable %in% c("var11", "var12"), 'One',
                                 ifelse(variable %in% c("var21", "var22"), 'Two', 'Three')))
```

Comment: That is exactly what was happening. Now I have a beautiful 3-column graph! Thank you.